# How to set the correct Intellisense configuration for include path in VS Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, emscripten

I am trying to work with Emscripten. I have the compiler set up and working and now I'd like to write some code.

However, the include for emscripten remains underlined in red and I can see this error:

`#include <emscripten/emscripten.h>`

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (D:\MYPROJECT\cpp\main.cpp).C/C++(1696)
cannot open source file "emscripten/emscripten.h"C/C++(1696)
```

A "Quick fix" (quotes intended) takes me to the Microsoft C/C++ Extension - IntelliSense Configurations. And there I can edit include paths. I have created a new configuration named EMSCRIPTEN and set these paths:

```
${workspaceFolder}/cpp/**
D:\lib\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\system\include
```

But this has no effect. Now if I do add this to the default configuration that was there from the start (Win32), it works. But I don't want to use that one for my emscripten project! I was kinda hoping to convince to IDE to compile my programs as well.

So how do I set per-workspace C++ compiler settings to a given configuration?

Comment: The include path for Intellisense is completely independent of building and is in the c_cpp_properties.json. The 3 json files that are used by default (unless you have some build extension like CMake Tools) are discussed here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: @drescherjm According to that document, I edited the right file, just using GUI. My question isn't how to set the include path, as I said it works with the Win32 configuration, but how to switch my workspace to another configuration from `c_cpp_properties.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found it, it's to the right bottom of the screen next to language type selection:

[image]